# net core doesn't rebuild project when embedded file is changed

Tags: visual-studio-2015, asp.net-core

When an embedded file is changed the rebuild is skipped.

```
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 0 failed, 5 up-to-date, 1 skipped ==========
```

The only option I found was an manual rebuild of the project.

my build options in project.json

```
"buildOptions": {
    "emitEntryPoint": true,
    "preserveCompilationContext": true,
    "embed": ["**/*.sql"]
  },
```

Answer (score 0):

A solution is to use `dotnet watch test` or `dotnet watch run`